# CUPS basic auth error through web interface

Tags: http-basic-authentication, cups

I'm trying to configure CUPS to allow remote administration through the web interface. There's [enough](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/cups-remote-admin-589038/) documentation [out](http://www.debianadmin.com/setup-cups-common-unix-printing-system-server-and-client-in-debian.html) there [that](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/cups-400-bad-request-812442/) I can figure out what to change in my `cupsd.conf` (changing `Listen localhost:631` to `Port 631`, and adding `Allow @LOCAL` to the `/`, `/admin` and `/admin/conf` sections).

I'm now at the point where I can see the CUPS interface from another machine on the same network. The trouble is, when I try to `Add Printer`, I'm asked for a username and password, but my response is rejected even when I know I've gotten it right (I assume it's asking for the username and password of someone in the `lpadmin` group on the server machine; I've `ssh`ed in with credentials its rejecting, and the user I'm using has been added to the `lpadmin` group).

If I disable auth outright, by changing `DefaultAuthType Basic` to `DefaultAuthType None`, I get an "Unauthorized" error instead of a password request when I try to `Add Printer`.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way of letting users from the local network to administer the print server through the CUPS web interface?

**EDIT the Second:**

I've now tested the same config changes on two different machines (first a Debian Squeeze box, and then another Wheezy box just to make sure) and the above config file works just fine on them. Are there any other permission/port settings that might affect CUPS remote administration other than what's contained in `cupsd.conf`? Is this getting specific enough that I should go ask `unix.se` instead?

**EDIT:**

By request, my complete `cupsd.conf` (spoiler: minimally edited default config file that comes with the edition of CUPS from the Debian wheezy repos):

```
LogLevel warn
MaxLogSize 0

SystemGroup lpadmin

Port 631
# Listen localhost:631
Listen /var/run/cups/cups.sock

Browsing On
BrowseOrder allow,deny
BrowseAllow all
BrowseLocalProtocols CUPS dnssd

# DefaultAuthType Basic
DefaultAuthType None

WebInterface Yes

<Location />
  Order allow,deny
  Allow @LOCAL
</Location>

<Location /admin>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow @LOCAL
</Location>

<Location /admin/conf>
  AuthType Default
  Require user @SYSTEM
  Order allow,deny
  Allow @LOCAL
</Location>

# Set the default printer/job policies...
<Policy default>
  # Job/subscription privacy...
  JobPrivateAccess default
  JobPrivateValues default
  SubscriptionPrivateAccess default
  SubscriptionPrivateValues default

  # Job-related operations must be done by the owner or an administrator...
  <Limit Create-Job Print-Job Print-URI Validate-Job>
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>

  <Limit Send-Document Send-URI Hold-Job Release-Job Restart-Job Purge-Jobs Set-Job-Attributes Create-Job-Subscription Renew-Subscription Cancel-Subscription Get-Notifications Reprocess-Job Cancel-Current-Job Suspend-Current-Job Resume-Job Cancel-My-Jobs Close-Job CUPS-Move-Job CUPS-Get-Document>
    Require user @OWNER @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>

  # All administration operations require an administrator to authenticate...
  <Limit CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer CUPS-Delete-Printer CUPS-Add-Modify-Class CUPS-Delete-Class CUPS-Set-Default CUPS-Get-Devices>
    AuthType Default
    Require user @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>

  # All printer operations require a printer operator to authenticate...
  <Limit Pause-Printer Resume-Printer Enable-Printer Disable-Printer Pause-Printer-After-Current-Job Hold-New-Jobs Release-Held-New-Jobs Deactivate-Printer Activate-Printer Restart-Printer Shutdown-Printer Startup-Printer Promote-Job Schedule-Job-After Cancel-Jobs CUPS-Accept-Jobs CUPS-Reject-Jobs>
    AuthType Default
    Require user @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>

  # Only the owner or an administrator can cancel or authenticate a job...
  <Limit Cancel-Job CUPS-Authenticate-Job>
    Require user @OWNER @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>

  <Limit All>
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
</Policy>

# Set the authenticated printer/job policies...
<Policy authenticated>
  # Job/subscription privacy...
  JobPrivateAccess default
  JobPrivateValues default
  SubscriptionPrivateAccess default
  SubscriptionPrivateValues default

  # Job-related operations must be done by the owner or an administrator...
  <Limit Create-Job Print-Job Print-URI Validate-Job>
    AuthType Default
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>

  <Limit Send-Document Send-URI Hold-Job Release-Job Restart-Job Purge-Jobs Set-Job-Attributes Create-Job-Subscription Renew-Subscription Cancel-Subscription Get-Notifications Reprocess-Job Cancel-Current-Job Suspend-Current-Job Resume-Job Cancel-My-Jobs Close-Job CUPS-Move-Job CUPS-Get-Document>
    AuthType Default
    Require user @OWNER @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>

  # All administration operations require an administrator to authenticate...
  <Limit CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer CUPS-Delete-Printer CUPS-Add-Modify-Class CUPS-Delete-Class CUPS-Set-Default>
    AuthType Default
    Require user @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>

  # All printer operations require a printer operator to authenticate...
  <Limit Pause-Printer Resume-Printer Enable-Printer Disable-Printer Pause-Printer-After-Current-Job Hold-New-Jobs Release-Held-New-Jobs Deactivate-Printer Activate-Printer Restart-Printer Shutdown-Printer Startup-Printer Promote-Job Schedule-Job-After Cancel-Jobs CUPS-Accept-Jobs CUPS-Reject-Jobs>
    AuthType Default
    Require user @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>

  # Only the owner or an administrator can cancel or authenticate a job...
  <Limit Cancel-Job CUPS-Authenticate-Job>
    AuthType Default
    Require user @OWNER @SYSTEM
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>

  <Limit All>
    Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
</Policy>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's usually asking for the CUPS server's root user/pass.

Please show us your cupsd.conf configuration file.

Comment: Done. And I need to say something to get past the minimum character limit.

Answer (score 1):

Configure password for root using the passwd. Then try access the url from the root user.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcktu.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured out a solution to our problem.  In the section:

```
# All administration operations require an administrator to authenticate...
  <Limit CUPS-Add-Modify-Printer CUPS-Delete-Printer CUPS-Add-Modify-Class CUPS-Delete-Class CUPS-Set-Default CUPS-Get-Devices>
AuthType Default
Require user @SYSTEM
Order deny,allow
```

change the "AuthType Default" to "AuthType None", you might also want to apply this change to all the other sections that involve configuring printers and managing jobs.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Why not just adding "DefaultAuthType None" ?

Comment: @Gill-Bates is right - `DefaultAuthType None` works as intended.